# Update database using Excel file having varying number of Columns

Tags: c#, sql, excel, code-behind, xls

I would like to update a table(Quotation)on button event in sql where the user imports an excel file with any number of columns and where one field 'Quotation No' can't be null or empty whereas other fields may or may not be null or empty.Also there are some spare(extra) columns in the database which the user can update.I have created another table(QuotationExtraColumn) so that the renamed extra field name is stored in the new table but the values are stored in the former Quotation table.The fields vendor no and equipment no are not fixed that is they should be taken as spare fields.

Right now what i can do is for the fixed columns i can update the data with or without values in each of them but for the spare fields i haven't got any idea as to what to do.
 The thing is that there is a xls upload with predefined column names with varying number of columns..but now what the requirement is that the client wants something like spare fields(columns) in the db so that if he requires a new field he can add the columns and from this generic update add values to the new field without even you know asking the developers to create a new field and its separate update functionality for it.

This is the code:

```
    protected void btnGenUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuGenUpdate.FileName);
    if (strExtension.ToLower() != ".xls" && strExtension.ToLower() != ".xlsx")
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please import valid file.";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMessage.CssClass = "error";
        return;
    }

    string strConnectionString = string.Empty;
    if (strExtension.ToLower() == ".xls")
    {
        strConnectionString = @"Datasource";
    }

    con.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
    con.Open();

    DataTable dtSchema = con.GetSchema("Tables");
    DataTable dtSheet = new DataTable();
    if (dtSchema != null && dtSchema.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + Convert.ToString(dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"]) + "]", con);
        da.Fill(dtSheet);

        bool isExistsQuotation = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < dtSheet.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName == "")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Please Enter Column Name.";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblMessage.CssClass = "error";
            }

            if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.Trim().ToLower() == "quotation no" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.Trim().ToLower() == "quotationno")
            {
                isExistsQuotation = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isExistsQuotation)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            lblMessage.Visible = false;
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertmessage", "EmptyQuotationNoColumn();", true);
            return;
        }


        string QuotationNo = "";
        string OrderNo = "";
        string JCF = "";
        string WBSNo = "";
        string Cost = "";
        string InvoiceNo = "";
        string SAPExpenses = "";
        string spare1 = "";
        string spare2 = "";
        string spare3 = "";
        string spare4 = "";
        string spare5 = "";
        string spare6 = "";
        string spare7 = "";
        string spare8 = "";
        int index1;
        int index2;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtSheet.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRow row = dtSheet.Rows[i];
                //int columnCount = dtSheet.Columns.Count;
                //string[] columns = new string[columnCount];
                //dtSheet.Columns.Contains();
                for (int j = 0; j < dtSheet.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "quotationno" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "quotation no")
                    {
                        QuotationNo = row[j].ToString();
                        if (QuotationNo == "")
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = "";
                            lblMessage.Visible = false;
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertmessage", "EmptyQuotationNo();", true);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "orderno" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "order no")
                    {
                        OrderNo = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "jcf")
                    {
                        JCF = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "wbsno" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "wbs no")
                    {
                        WBSNo = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "cost")
                    {
                        Cost = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "invoiceno" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "invoice no")
                    {
                        InvoiceNo = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "sapexpenses" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "sap expenses")
                    {
                        SAPExpenses = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "vendorno" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "vendor no")
                    {
                        //index1 = dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower().IndexOf("vendorno");
                        spare1 = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                 //vendorno is spare1 and equipmentno is spare2
                    if (dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "equipmentno" || dtSheet.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToLower() == "equipment no")
                    {

                        spare2 = row[j].ToString();
                    }
                }

                int count = Quotation.InsertGenericUpdate(QuotationNo, OrderNo, JCF, WBSNo, InvoiceNo, Cost, SAPExpenses, spare1, spare2);
                temp += count;
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                if (temp != 0)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Generic Update Successful : " + temp + " Row(s) Updated";
                }
                else { lblMessage.Text = "Enter proper data"; }
            }
            catch
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Generic Update Unsuccessful: No Rows Updated";
            }
            finally { con.Close(); con.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please import valid file.";
        lblMessage.CssClass = "error";
        return;
    }
}
```

SQL code without the spare fields is:

```
    SET @orderno = CASE WHEN (@orderno = '') THEN null WHEN (@orderno != '') THEN @orderno END
SET @jcf = CASE WHEN (@jcf = '') THEN NULL WHEN (@jcf != '') THEN @jcf END
SET @wbs = CASE WHEN (@wbs = '') THEN null WHEN (@wbs != '') THEN @wbs END
SET @invoiceno = CASE WHEN (@invoiceno = '') THEN null WHEN (@invoiceno != '') THEN @invoiceno END
SET @cost = CASE WHEN (@cost = '') THEN null WHEN (@cost != '') THEN @cost END
SET @sapexpenses = CASE WHEN (@sapexpenses = '') THEN null WHEN (@sapexpenses != '') THEN @sapexpenses END

UPDATE [AFS].[dbo].[Quotation]      
    SET [OrderNo] = ISNULL(@orderno,[OrderNo]),
        [JCF] = ISNULL(@jcf,JCF),
        [WBSNo] = ISNULL(@wbs,WBSNo),
        [InvoiceNo] = ISNULL(@invoiceno,InvoiceNo),
        [Cost] = ISNULL(@cost,Cost),
        [SAPExpenses] = ISNULL(@sapexpenses,SAPExpenses)
    WHERE [QuotationNo] = @quotationno;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `QuotationExtraColumn`?

Comment: That table contains 2 fields: Columnid,and ColumnName..The renamed field will be ColumnName so that i dont have to rename the quotation table which will be always like spare 1 2 and so on.